# Using Firebase functions for iOS app and web admin and how to manage Github repo

Tags: ios, firebase, github, web-applications, google-cloud-functions

I have questions regarding Firebase functions for iOS app and web admin.

So.. Here's a circumstance.

1. I'm working on to build an admin page to manage users' actions and requests on an iOS app.
2. For the iOS app, its backend is built entirely with firebase.
3. So there are two Github repos, one for iOS app and one for admin & two index.js for firebase functions. And one single Firestore.

My concern is... If I do "firebase deploy --only functions" on admin page and forget to mention "not to wipe out" functions from functions used in iOS app, that could cause problem to the live app.

So, someone suggested me to write codes in iOS app's index.js for firebase functions for the admin's backend.

And, I want to know what's the best practice in this case TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase deploy will only delete functions if you (a) use the `functions:delete` CLI command or (b) if you remove the function from you `index.js` before deploying. When you `firebase deploy --only functions`, it will deploy any new ones and redeploy any existing ones.

If what you're saying is that you have your functions in two different repos, then you have two options:

1. Combine them into a single repo - I don't know why you'd have admin functions source code in your iOS repo anyways. Using Firebase functions on the client merely *calls* a function. The source code can be elsewhere.
2. But assuming your source code *needs* to be in multiple repos (or that's how you want it), you should then never call `firebase deploy --only functions`. Instead, set up your deploy workflow or process to deploy the specific functions in that repo so it doesn't affect any other functions. Something like this:

```sh
firebase deploy --only functions:iosFunc1,functions:iosFunc2
firebase deploy --only functions:adminFuncA,functions:adminFuncB
```

When you explicitly define which functions to deploy, it won't affect any other functions.

But I'd seriously consider separating the functions back-end code from your iOS client side code if for no other reason than removing the possibility of potentially leaking admin credentials to the client.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Here’s one more question.

So let’s say web app and iOS app shares same firebase projects and firestore. Their “index.js” files are in two different repos, iOS repo and web admin repo. The two “index.js” files don’t share any codes or Firebase Functions. 

If I run “firebase deploy —only functions” on web admin repo, I’d not affect the Firebase Functions in ios repo?

Comment: If they are using the same Firebase project and the same Firebase functions, running `firebase deploy --only functions` from your iOS directory will upload all your iOS functions and delete anything else. And vice versa. So if you want to keep separate index.js files, each with their own functions, but want to push them to the same Firebase project, you should specify the name of each function like I did in my answer so that you're not letting Firebase delete functions from the one repo when you deploy from the other.